# Joomla v2.5 date not pulling in from DB

Tags: date, joomla, echo

Issue on a Joomla v2.5.6 module.

Code used:

```
<?php echo $date->toFormat(JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3')); ?>
```

Pulling from table column:

```
2013-01-26
```

Should be pulling back as:
**26 January 2013**

But the above is just pulling back "**d F Y**"

Any ideas?

FIXED:

```
<?php echo $date->Format(JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3')); ?>
```

**Format not toFormat**

Comment: try to print JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3') individually to see if it is getting the proper format

Comment: ...and <?php echo $date; ?> pulls back 2012-12-22 00:00:00 correctly

Comment: ah... this does it... <?php echo $date->Format(JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3')); ?> ... toFormat was the issue

Comment: Divide and conquer. One of you two need to write this up as an answer, so it can be accepted.

Comment: please write an answer and accept it so it doesnt look like an unanswered question. thanks